# about linux servers timezone

Tags: linux, timezone

which timezone linux servers uses ? I mean does all the hosting servers use UTC timezone or uses their local time zone ? I'm developing a penny auction script, so it's very important me to know . Plz, anyone help.

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: This is nonsense. Linux servers use whatever the local timezone is. It's configurable, just like every other operating system. Do a little research or thinking before asking questions.

Comment: All of them. You can open 17 different windows and set a different time zone in each.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on how the servers are configured, I doubt all hosting providers use the same settings. For how to set system-wide timezone, have a look at [Linux, Clocks, and Time](http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/time.html).

Note that some distributions might offer alternative ways of setting the timezone.

Also, the timezone can be set per-session with the `TZ` environment variable:

```
$ date
Mon May 16 12:26:34 CEST 2011
$ export TZ=UTC
$ date
Mon May 16 10:26:40 UTC 2011
$ export TZ=America/New_York
$ date
Mon May 16 06:26:44 EDT 2011
```

Simply use `date +%Z` to get your current timezone on the command line (or `date +%z` for the offset value like `+0200` for CEST right now - but be careful with DST issues if you use plain offsets).

Some languages/runtimes provide other means to set the timezone either via configuration files or special functions (e.g. PHP's [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)).

Look in the `/usr/share/zoneinfo` directory to see all the available timezones on your system.

Comment: oh! thanks for ur answer . I have found the solution. whatever the time settings is I'll calculate basing on that and Unix timestamp, so I need not worry about time settings.